# Error while calling readMetadata() ，unable to find end tag at: START_TAG seen

Tags: api, metadata-api, metadata

I have written a Java code for getting the metadata though [readMetadata()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_readMetadata.htm),
but the following error is always reported after fetching a portion of the data:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...... @3:20499

Caused by: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...... @3:20499**

I really did not find a good solution，Has anyone encountered a similar situation? How to solve it?

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000mNUARAA4/~) that when trying to retrieve metadata of an Object when there is a GeoLocation field using Metadata API jar, it throws this error.